# Python exponential calculation on fraction

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to calculate 27^(1/3) = 3. But it turns out not as expected.

```
>>> 27 ** (1/3)
1
>>> 27 ** (1/3.)
3.0
```

Firstly, why the first calculation will result in 1, is it because 1/3 is casted to an int so it equals zero?

Secondly, what does the '.' means in Python in general, could I append a dot to any number in order to cast it from int to double?

Thanks.

Comment: All your guesses are correct. Keep in mind, in python-3, numbers are floating points by default.

Comment: @mehmetminanc:  In Python 3, numbers are **not** floating point by default. If you write an integer literal in Python 3 it's still an integer. However, the `/` division operator always performs floating-point division.

Comment: FWIW, this is one of the very first topics covered in the official Python 2 [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers). "The return type of a division (/) operation depends on its operands. If both operands are of type int, floor division is performed and an int is returned. If either operand is a float, classic division is performed and a float is returned. The // operator is also provided for doing floor division no matter what the operands are."

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, I am actually quite surprised. Is there any practical significance between both, though?

Comment: @mehmetminanc: "Is there any practical significance between integers and floats"? Certainly! Python integers can be as large as you want (given memory constraints); floats have a limited range, and limited precision. See Wikipedia's article on [Floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for details. Python uses [IEEE 754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) for its floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firstly, why the first calculation will result in 1, is it because 1/3
>   is casted to an int so it equals zero?

Yes, that's exactly it.

> what does the '.' means in Python in general, could I append a dot to
>   any number in order to cast it from int to double?

The `.` is explicitly making the number a float as `1.0` would be opposed to just `1`.

Comment: Addendum: Switch to python 3, where division with `/` always gives you a float. Much easier to work with.

Comment: @alexis Totally agree. Python 3 is <3

Answer (score 2):

You experience integer division in python 2.

in python 2:

```
>>> 2/3
0
```

In python 3:

```
>>> 2/3
0.6666666
```

If you want the python3 behaviour in python2 you can do

```
from __future__ import division
```

as your first import.

For the integer division, use

```
>>> 2 // 3
0
```

Or you can use `2.0 / 3.0` to use `float`s.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.x, dividing integers defaults to floor division, so any non-integer quotient automatically rounds down to the nearest integer for example

```
>>> 1/3
0
>>> 5/2
2
```

So when you try to calculate 27 ** (1/3) you are just calculating 27 ** 0

There are numerous workarounds to the problem, the simplest way would be to just use floating points in the exponent - (1.0/3.0), or even just (1/3.0). However, if you were to be doing a lot of these calculations it might become annoying to constantly type out all the numbers in floating point form. In this case, you could use the **future** module to utilize Python 3.x division behavior, which always results in a floating point value:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/3
0.3333333333333333
```

This way the calculation will never default to floor division. And if at some point you want floor division in the same program, you can just use the // operator to get behavior similar to python 2.x integer division, like so:

```
>>> 1//3
0
```